# Can users put answers into the "low quality" queue?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I came across this (almost?) "link only" answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932776/reactjs-fixeddatatable-sorting-and-filtering-example-not-working/43178117#43178117).

If this answer be shown to me when reviewing the "lqp" queue, I would go for "delete as link-only".

But when I just notice the answer my coincidence; putting a delete flag sounds "wrong"; as the closest fitting category would be:

**very low quality**

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is
>   unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be
>   removed.

But: this answer could be easily improved by editing, couldn't it?

Is this just "bad wording" on the flag reasons; or am I missing something?

Comment: If you flag as very low quality you're basically saying you think it should be deleted. Given that you have 20K you can just downvote and then vote to delete the answer if you think it has no value. That's the same effect as delete as link-only in the review queue.

Comment: Like Triage, "editing" does not mean *the author*'s editing, but *J. Random 2ker*'s editing. Flag or VTD or both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all "link only" answers can be improved by editing. I would never make edits that drastically change the answer, even edits that "only" paste relevant parts from the linked website into the answer.

So the question is: Do we really want to wait for all answers to be improved by the OP? This will add many noise to Stack Overflow, and we want to reduce it.

I think you should vote to delete, regardless of the fact that the post could be improved.